# Java Linked List "insertAfter" - method

Tags: java

```
public void insertAfter(String after, String newName, int newPunkte)
{
    ListNode newNode = new ListNode(newName, newPunkte, null);

    if(head == null)
    {
        System.out.println("'InsertAfter' is not possible.");
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        current = head;

        while(current != null)
        {
            if(current.getName().equals(after))
            {
                System.out.println(after+" was found. "+newName+" was created.");
                //Here is my problem...
                current.setNext(newNode);
                return;
            }
            previous = current;
            current = current.getNext();
        }
        System.out.println(after+" was not found.");
        return;

    }
}
```

Hey guys, Ive got a little problem with my code. When I insert a new Node after
a (if so) found Node, the following Nodes (after the new one) are disappearing..
I pretty sure that the problem is that i didnt set "previous" after inserting.
Im pretty inexperienced with implementing Linked Lists.
I hope you can help me:)

By the way for understanding my code: The parameter "newPunkte" means "newPoints".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the next node on newNode:

```
ListNode next = current.getNext();
current.setNext(newNode);
newNode.setNext(next);
```

Comment: Thank you :)  Helped me a lot!